# Qt Resize of QListView

Tags: qt, qlistview, qsizepolicy

I would like to adjust a QListView's width according to its content to let every item visible.
The list is like:

```
...
setFlow(QListView::LeftToRight) ;
setLayoutMode(QListView::Batched);
setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
setAutoScroll(false);
setUniformItemSizes(true);
setResizeMode(QListView::Adjust);
...
```

I tried different QSizePolicy and got really confused.

Comment: check what [sizeHint](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qwidget.html#sizeHint-prop) for `QListView` returns when numbers of items is changed. If always same value then size policy won't help.

Comment: @MarekR Ty for your comment.It's always the same. If I redefine sizeHint() for my listview, how can I calculate the right width to fit all items?

Comment: @MarekR Ok. I calculated with sizeHintForColumn() in sizeHint().

Answer (score 0):

This switch:

```
setUniformItemSizes(true);
```

turns on some optimizations of the QListView. Seems like the optimized code does not calculate the layout when qlistview is resized.
Try setting setUniformItemSizes(false) and your qlistview should adapt to the item sizes.